# Proving the distance between two points is 1 on a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, continuity

this is a tough question.

We suppose $f$ is continuous on $[0,2]$ and $f(0) = f(2)$. We want to prove $\exists$ $x, y \in [0,2]$ such that $ \lvert y-x \rvert = 1 $ and $ f(x) = f(y)$.

- My attempt

Just from the fact $f(0) =f(2)$ I imagined an upside down parabola with roots at $0$ and $2$. We define a function $g(x) = f(x+1) - f(x)$ on $[0,1]$. We also recognize that $y = x \pm 1$ because the distance between the two points is 1.

I have no idea how to proceed from here.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This feels like a job for the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: How can you say that without much work? I am just curious - I want to get to a point where I can say things like this.

Comment: It's just a hunch based on experience - but I could be wrong.  I'll have to think about it more to make a more concrete suggestion.

Comment: But what about this problem gives you a hunch that IVT is involved? haha @GregoryGrant

Comment: @DavidSouth Indeed the answer somebody posted below does use the IVT.  I got the hunch based on the fact that the problem involves: (1) a *continuous* function defined on an *interval* of the real line where we are given information about values at the *endpoints*. (2) The need to demonstrate the existence of a point within the interval where the continuous function does something in particular.  Those two ingredients will make it smell like the IVT every time.

Comment: perFECT answer. I love answers like these. Thank you so much.

Comment: @DavidSouth Glad to help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without loss of generality, let $y = x + 1$. Define $g(x) = f(x+1) - f(x), 0 \leq x \leq 1$. This function is continuous on $[0, 1]$ since $f(x)$ is continuous. Observe that
$$
g(1) = f(2) - f(1)
$$
and
$$
g(0) = f(1) - f(0) = f(1) - f(2)
$$
If $f(2) = f(1)$, we've find a $(x, y)$ pair satisfying the problem with $x = 1, y = 2$. Otherwise, since one of $g(1)$ and $g(0)$ is greater than $0$ and another is less than $0$, there must exists a $x' \in [0, 1]$ such that $g(x')=0$ since $g(x)$ is continuous. Then $f(x') = f(x' + 1)$.

Comment: Every statement in this answer makes sense, but I don't understand how showing $f(x') = f(x'+1)$ shows that the distance between these two points is 1.

Comment: |x'-(x'+1)| = ...

Comment: Ah, okay. Makes sense thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(0)=f(2)=h$,and define $G(x) =f(x)-h$,so $G(0)=G(2)=0$.   Let $y=c,c$ constant,be a horizontal linear function. suppose that $G(k)=m$ be the max (or the min) of $G(x)$ in $[0,2]$. Let,G(x)=y(x)=c; It's obvious that this equation have two roots in $[0,2]$ for all $0<=c<m$ .Lets call this roots $R_1(c)$,$R_2(c)$,defined as functions of c. let $H(c)= |R_1(c)-R_2(c)|$, so $H(c)$ is continuous (why?) in $[0,m]$ and H(0)=2 and H(m)=0, so exist n in $[0,m]$ such $H(n)=1$, and this prove the result.